# "TooManyMessages" Error coming from c2dm.intent.RECEIVE Intent

Tags: php, android, broadcastreceiver, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

Does anyone have any documentation on this **"TooManyMessages" error**.

After I call the GoogleCloudMessaging send method I am getting an intent from **com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE** with the following key/value pairs in the extras bundle.

```
Send error:
Bundle[{error=TooManyMessages, 
message_type=send_error, 
google.message_id=1, 
android.support.content.wakelockid=1}
```

Comment: share the server side code

Comment: I have client side code.Actually for testing I am sending message from android application and try to get message to same application on same device.Is this looks a problem?

Comment: you must be contacting a server or you must me making your phone behave like a server... in either case please share the code that you use to send message. One rational explanation is given by Eran as one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

This means that too many messages were stored in the GCM server for a single device without being delivered (which might happen if your device was offline while many messages were sent by your server).

Once the number of such messages reaches the limit,  which is 100 if you don't use a collapse key, they are deleted from the GCM server,  and you get that error message,  which informes you your device should sync with your server in order to get the lost messages.