# GCM Extras Error: "TooManyMessages"

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to follow the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) for setting up a GCM client.

**The Situation**

After having set up everything just like in the guide,
I am able to send a message over to the GCM, using:

```
gcm.send
```

Then, exactly as should happen, the broadcaster calls to my intent's OnReceived procedure.

So far so good.

**The Problem**

Upon receiving the actual data, meaning - the intent's extras as a Bundle object, a problem occurs.

The extras' content (toString) contains an error:

```
Bundle[{error=TooManyMessages, 
message_type=send_error, 
google.message_id=1, 
android.support.content.wakelockid=1}
```

**The Meaning**

Now, I've done my research, but came up with no practical answers. Only an explanation as to what is happening. [Here is the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932234/toomanymessages-error-coming-from-c2dm-intent-receive-intent), and its explanation:

`This means that too many messages were stored in the GCM server for a single device without being delivered (which might happen if your device was offline while many messages were sent by your server).`

`Once the number of such messages reaches the limit, which is 100 if you don't use a collapse key, they are deleted from the GCM server, and you get that error message, which informes you your device should sync with your server in order to get the lost messages.`

**The Question**

So, according to the answer, I am to sync my device with the server. How, exactly?

Also note, I have not created a GCM server. I'm only using the official GCM client implementation.

**Thanks in advance to those who help!**

**-P**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you are trying to send and to whom. The `gcm.send` method sends a message from your application to your server. For the message to big delivered, you must implement a server that connects to the GCM Cloud Connection Server. Since you don't have a server, GCM can't send the message to your server, and stores the message. Once too many messages are stored, you get the `TooManyMessages` error.

You must implement a server in order to use GCM. If you only want to send messages from the server to your app, you can use the simpler GCM HTTP API. If you need to send messages from your app to your server, you should use the GCM CCS API.

The answer you are referring to describes a different situation in which you can get `TooManyMessages` error (when the server sends many messages to the same device, but GCM can't deliver those messages), but it's not relevant to your situation.

Comment: Hi Eran, many thanks. I was honestly vying for your reply after seeing your activity around these parts of SO.

So what you're saying is I have to implement a GCM server. Is it possible to do so in PHP?

Comment: @Porkel You're welcome! Yes, you have to implement a GCM server. It can be written in whatever language you feel comfortable with, as long as that language is capable of sending HTTP requests (if you are connecting to GCM HTTP server) or has some XMPP library (if you are connecting to GCM CCS server).

Comment: So I may have missed something here. Why would I ever want to have a GCM.send() message within the client? Why is there no parameter for a recipient?

Comment: @Porkel You'd want it only if you wish to send a message from your app to your server. This only works if your server establishes a XMPP connection to the GCM CCS server. In that case, you don't need to specify a recipient, since the recipient is always your server (the recipient is implicit - it's the sender ID you used to register the app to GCM).

Comment: I think I understand it all better now thanks to you, Eran. Much appreciated.

I'd highly appreciate it if you could verify my understanding of the matter:
My task is to basically establish a communication between two devices, sending complex messages (strings) back and forth. With that in mind, all I have to do is to implement a GCM server (HTTP, PHP would be my choice), transmit the message + receiver ID to the server, and have the server itself send the message over to the recipient via the GCM. Is that correct?